# In R, why are residuals of lm() and summary(lm()) different when using weights for the regression?

Tags: r, regression, residuals

I am using a decay weighting scheme for time series regression in financial markets (idea is that more recent data is more relevant). However `lm()` residuals are different from `summary(lm())` residuals. Is there a reason for this?

```
rr <- rnorm(500) * 50
xx <- 1:500
yy <- xx + rr
dd <- decay(500, 150)
sd(rr)
[1] 50.31787
sd(lm(yy ~ xx)$residuals)
    [1] 50.29099
    sd(summary(lm(yy ~ xx))$residuals)
[1] 50.29099
sd(lm(yy ~ xx, weights = dd)$residuals)
    [1] 50.29154
    sd(summary(lm(yy ~ xx, weights = dd))$residuals)
[1] 2.278805
dd2 <- c(rep(1, 250), rep(2, 250))
sd(lm(yy ~ xx, weights = dd2)$residuals)
    [1] 50.29102
    sd(summary(lm(yy ~ xx, weights = dd2))$residuals)
[1] 62.66624
```

here is my decay function, by the way:

```
decay <- function(len, halflife, sumone = TRUE) {
#function generates an exponentially decaying series
    t <- len:1 # generate a series of numbers reverse order so biggest weights last
    lambda <- log(2) / halflife #figure out the lambda for the halflife
    w <- exp(-lambda * t) #create the weights series  
    if(sumone) w <- w / sum(w) #normalise sum to 1 if necessary
    return(w) 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [help page](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/summary.lm.html) for `summary.lm` explains that `summary.lm` returns "the *weighted* residuals, the usual residuals rescaled by the square root of the weights specified in the call to `lm`." So to reproduce the result, type

```
sd(summary(lm(yy ~ xx, weights = dd))$residuals/sqrt(dd))
```

This should yield the same result as

```
sd(lm(yy ~ xx, weights = dd)$residuals)
```